# Apache fails to start as a service, but starts fine in debug mode

Tags: apache-2.2, fedora

For reference, this is Apache 2.2.15 on Fedora 13.

When I try to start httpd as a service like this, it fails:

```
# sudo service httpd start
Starting httpd:                                            [FAILED]
```

Nothing in the /etc/httpd/logs/error_log file.

I tried running it interactively in debug mode like this:

```
# sudo httpd -e DEBUG
```

And it runs just fine...

Any idea what could cause it to fail when being run as a service? Thanks.

Comment: Did you search in other logs (syslog, messages, etc)?

Comment: Nothing in /var/log/messages... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was SELinux. Sometimes that blasted thing causes more trouble than it's worth.